# Two like buttons on one url

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I want two like buttons on my subpages, so the users can express they opinion (the two like buttons have speperated functions)

My URLs are like this: www.example.com/category/123-page-name/

I added the like buttons this way (i used the GET variables):

first:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/category/123-page-name/" send="false" layout="box_count" width="100" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

second:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.example.com/category/123-page-name/?variable=1" send="false" layout="box_count" width="100" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

but it behaves strange... On some pages it works, but on some not and the two like buttons showing the same number...

So my question is: what do i need to setup in the header to get this to work properly? Do i need maybe the GET variable for the first like button too?

Thank you very much!

Comment: are you setting different `og:url` value based on the query string?

Comment: yes, but the user is default on the page that dosn't have GET variables. So this page needs the two like buttons with seperated URL-s.

Answer (score 0):

If you have open graph tags on your page then Facebook will use the open graph URL.

Comment: The og:url tag is dynamic (if($_GET['variable']==1)){...}

Comment: Have you tried scraping the URLs using the Facebook debug tools? I'm not familier with your code, if you are setting og:url in JavaScript then this clearly won't work.